# How to know from where I'm getting the data on windows?

Tags: windows-7, internet, url

I m' running on windows 7 x64. I have one software which retrieves data from internet and i'm interesting its source URL, how can i know from where i'm getting the data?
Is there any software ?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [`wireshark`](http://www.wireshark.org/) and have it sniff the network traffic.

Comment: I want to know DNS real URL(like www.example.com/bla-bla.bla) there are only ip adresses or i couldn't find it?

Comment: @Jamshid Asatillayev: See the documentation regarding [name resolution](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvNameResolutionSection.html).

Comment: *> I want to know DNS real URL*   “Domain name” `;-)`

Answer (score 0):

[Active ports](http://download.cnet.com/Active-Ports/3000-2651_4-29653.html) is a small utility that works pretty well for single use type situations.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [packet-sniffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_analyzer) to view and capture the data. [SmartSniff](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html) is one of the easiest to use.

You can see the associated domain name by checking the *Resolve IP Addresses*—which is enabled by default.

[image]